# Existe un trabajo que genera bloqueos en la Master

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me estoy encontrando con un bloqueo que está generando el sa(Este usuario está deshabilitado para loguearse) y lo que me dice es que su estatus es: `BACKGROUND`   y su comando es : `TRACE QUEUE TASK`

si intento hacer kill me dice:

```
Msg 6107, Level 14, State 1, Line 60
Sólo se pueden eliminar los procesos de usuario.
```

Gracias por su apoyo

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que está bloqueando?

Comment: Pues eso. No es un proceso que haya lanzado una sesión del usuario, sino una tarea programada de algún tipo. Como pudiste ver, es una tarea en segundo plano, así que no puedes detenerla así. Debes identificar el proceso que la lanza y ajustarlo para que no se lance de nuevo / se detenga

Comment: Hola respondo a lo s comentarios  Pues bloquea a otro proceso que dice estar haciendo un DELETE en la base de datos MSDB que de igual forma tiene estatus : BACKGROUND

Comment: y del segundo comentario: Pues me queda claro que es un proceso del sistema sin embargo no una tarea programada porque yo hago los JOB y no existe ninguno que trabaje con la master y un trace tampoco porque no tengo ninguno abierto